# Retention /Information management policy workflow issue where duplicate files created in destination

Tags: workflow, information-management

The policy is setup at the library/folder level. The associated action is to start a workflow. This is one of 2 active wfs enabled on that library.

The workflow copies the item to another existing folder in the same site. Then the workflow deletes the orig item in the orig folder.

The issue/ problem is that for every file copied, another duplicate file is also created. This duplicate file has a date time stamp appended to it. Ex. FilenameXyz 2013-07-31T16_35_42(2018-10-17_18-31-22_93345).xml

So I end up with 2 files!
FilenameXyz 2013-07-31T16_35_42.xml, 
FilenameXyz 2013-07-31T16_35_42(2018-10-17_18-31-22_93345).xml

Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you or whoever "published" the workflow has the right permissions on site level and on that specific folder/document library e.g. *Full Control*. Also if you're using Sharepoint 2013 WF then you might need to put the copy/delete actions in **App Step**. But since you're using retention policy to invoke the workflow it must be Sharepoint 2010 WF which requires **Impersonation step** to perform elevated copy/remove tasks from outside of the associated list. Hope this helps!